# Python raises Tesseract Error (raise TesseractError(status, errors))

Tags: python, image, tesseract, python-imaging-library

I have been searching the forum for the error that I had had, but no one seemed to have the same error that my program had. 
I am coding a program using csv, Pillow, and pytesseract to convert a grab the texts in the image, split the text, and append it to a csv file.

### The image looks like:

Name: Example

Email: Example

Phone: Example

---

so that I can

```
text.pop(1) #for the Name
text.pop(3) #for the Email
text.pop(5) #for the phonenumber
```

and then append it to a list, and then write it on a csv file.

So,

The code basically goes like:

```
def Main(self):
    im = Image.open(r'C:\Users\Desktop\test.tif')
    im.load()
    print im
    i = image_to_string(im)
    print i
    self.info_list = str.split(i)

    Name = self.info_list.pop(1) 
    Email = self.info_list.pop(3)
    Phone = self.info_list.pop(5)

    print "Name: " + Name
    print "Email: " + Email
    print "Phone: " + Phone

    self.information = []
    self.information.append(Name)
    self.information.append(Email)
    self.information.append(Phone)

    with open('Information.csv', 'w') as fp:
        wr = csv.writer(fp, dialect='excel')
        data=['Name', 'Email', 'Phone', 'Notes']
        wr.writerow(data)
        wr.writerow(self.information)
```

The error I get is

```
    raise TesseractError(status, errors) 
TesseractError: (1, '')
```

Thanks for reading my post, and I would really appreciate some advice!

Edit

---

I tried it again, and I get this error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Desktop.....'
```

Any help?